# Android transparent activity cannot make action in background activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Hi I am working with android.I had created an app in which I had called second activity as intent and I make its background transparent.Second Activity contains a button and when click on it it shows a slidedrawer. After calling 2nd one I can view 1st activity because 2nd activity background is transparent.But How can I make an action even when the 2nd activity is  also there ???

here is my code

1st activity

```
   public   class MainActivity5 extends Activity  {



    @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.blah);
      Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
      b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intnt = new Intent(MainActivity5.this,
                    GestureActivity.class);
              startActivity(intnt);

             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "clicked",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       }
     });

     }



     }
```

2nd activity

```
  public class GestureActivity extends Activity  {


   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "library", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      }
    }
```

activity_main1.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
style="@style/CustomTheme" >






<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="330dip"
    android:layout_height="450dip"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/handle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>



        <RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
      android:background="#fe6e6e" 
    android:id="@+id/content">
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Login Form" 
     android:layout_marginLeft="170px"
     android:textColor="#101010"
     android:textStyle="bold"
     android:textSize="20sp"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="User Name-"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:textColor="#480000"
    android:textSize="18sp"/>


   <EditText
    android:id="@+id/userName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:width="160px" >


 </EditText>

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/userName"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:text="Password - " 
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#480000"
    android:textSize="18sp"/>

  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/userName"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:width="160px" >


  </EditText>

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="130px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/password"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/password"
    android:text="Login" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/reset"
    android:layout_width="130px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/login"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/login"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/password"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
    android:text="Reset" />

 </RelativeLayout>


</SlidingDrawer>

</LinearLayout>
```

is it possible to make both activity can run at the same time ???

Comment: No.It's not possible.

Comment: how can I make both activity run at same time??

Comment: You can run multiple `Fragments` but not multiple `Activities.` And if it is only about showing another layout on top of previous layout then use `FrameLayout` to display another layout.

Comment: Anyhow what is the use of of displaying another Activity on top?

Comment: My second activty is an ad layer. So I want to ad a swipe ads in apps :) Is there any simple methods to implement this  ??

Answer (score 0):

No yaar you can't run both activities at the same time .You will get a clear idea about this if you know the activity lifecycle.

Below is the link which gives clear idea about activity lifecycle

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html